# Problem with inverse transform of a scaled array using sklearn MimMaxScaler

Tags: python-3.x, scaling

I am not sure what am I doing wrong here.
Here is my code:

```
def transform_data(dataset):
     scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0,1))
     scaler = scaler.fit(dataset)
     data_s = scaler.transform(dataset)
    return data_s

train_data_s = transform_data(train_data)

print(train_data_s.shape)
train_data_s[1]
```

(422, 2)
array([0.39817897, 0.34021824])

**Inverse transforming the data...**

```
test = scaler.inverse_transform(train_data_s)
```

**I get following error:**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call 
last)
 <ipython-input-692-a021cb236785> in <module>
  ----> 1 test = scaler.inverse_transform(train_data_s1)
        2 #test.head()

 ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in inverse_transform(self, X)
    404                         force_all_finite="allow-nan")
    405 
 --> 406         X -= self.min_
    407         X /= self.scale_
    408         return X

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (422,2) (3,) (422,2)
```

Comment: Solved the problem. It was using scaler object from older code where I had 3 columns.

Comment: Welcome! You can consider deleting your question. You found out what was the problem, and it is very unlikely that someone else will face the same.